# Making a QT-creator Application communicate with a Microcontroller

Tags: c++, qt, microcontroller

Currently I want to create a qt application on my Desktop that say, has 3 buttons. These 3 buttons can change certain variables for my device, which will be connected to the desktop with a microcontroller.

I want my desktop application to be able to communicate with the microcontroller. For example, clicking a button might flip a certain boolean variable and the microcontroller will adjust accordingly.

I have no idea how to start and what sort of questions I should be asking and how to tackle this at a high level.

Thank you.

My desktop is a macbook pro retina 15-inch 2014 and my microcontroller is either an Teensy, or an Intel Atom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to look at is what communication buses are common between your desktop computer and your microcontroller. Does your microcontroller have USB or ethernet capabilities? Does your microcontroller have expansion boards for WiFi or bluetooth support? Do you have access to an I2C bus in your desktop PC?

Depending on the answers above, if your microcontroller and your computer do not share common communication buses, you might have to use intermediary hardware, for instance, you might want to use something like the FTDI USB (on your desktop) to UART (for the microcontroller) cables, you can find those here: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm

In that case I'd recommend using a cable with VCD drivers, so the cable appears as a Serial port to your computer, which you can access in QT by using QSerialPort (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html)

There would be other similar solutions, but I'd say that, if there are no shared buses between your microcontroller and host, this would be one of the most universal. Maybe if you specify your microcontroller or embedded board We could help a little more.

Comment: Hi, I am using a macbook pro and either Teensy or Intel Atom. I was also wondering if you know what the difference between QSerialPort and Qextserialport is? https://github.com/qextserialport/qextserialport

Comment: Qextserialport has existed for a long time. Dates back to even Qt 2.0 days, when Qt did not provide a serial port API.Since 5.1, Qt officially supports serial port communications. I'd advise using qserialport if your version of Qt sports it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what type of microcontroller you are using, but if it has support for UART you can use the QSerialPort lib (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) to send data using a serial port.

In case of an arduino, you can send messages using this lib directly via the USB emulated COM port. If it don't have USB emulated COM port, you should use a serial adapter (an Arduino board can play this role).

Comment: I was wondering if you know if the Intel Atom can use the QSerialPort lib? If so, would I simply apply the following: 1) Have GUI activate certain serial message if button is pressed 2) Have Intel Atom listen for serial message and then change accordingly?